How to mock an image file in react Jest testing library to check image width and height
I am writing a jest unit test to display error message when user click file upload button when image width and height ratio is  3 :1.
Here is method I used to check image ratio:
export const isValidRatio = async (file: File) => {
  return createImageBitmap(file).then((bitmap) => {
    return bitmap.width / bitmap.height === 3;
  });
};

In the Jest , I have following way to mock File
    const blob = new Blob(['test blog'], { type: 'image/png' });
    const testFile = new File([blob], 'testFile01.jpeg', { type: 'image/jpeg' });

It works well to test if file size above certain limitation, however, I have been struggle a lot to test width & height ratio.
Does anyone know what is a good approach to mock an image width & height?

Can you import actual images and process their data normally? Store your images in your mocks folder and import them like any other file (assuming you have the right loader available to handle it); or convert it to a base64 representation and store that as a normal .js/.mjs/.cjs export

Good suggestion, let me try to investigate how to do it.
